# Searching in mega size multidimentional array using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, preg-match

I have a table of millions records with some multidimensional array. I need to search in each row to find a match, the key matches are in another table with thousands of records.

for instance, each person might have different number of educations separated by ; (semi colon). I am aiming to find those with education in UK when searching with a table of UK's institute.

```
Name        | Educations
------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Smith  | Oxford University, BSc Business, UK ; London University, MSc Art, UK ; Boston University, PhD in AI, USA
Sara Jones  | Ealing college, Access to IT, UK ; Paris University, BSc Maths, France
```

Currently I amusing preg_match but putting a large list of institutes into an array with | (pipe line) separator doesn't seem to work. Though, limiting the array to less than 1000 seems to work. I am not sure if this is something to do with array size?

I would appreciate any advice on how to optimize the search for large size array with preg_match or any other search functions that you are aware of.

Here is part of my code:

```
// query a list of institute  
$query = "SELECT institute_name FROM $table_institute limit 1000"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// create an array of institute
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   $institute = trim($row['institute_name']); 
   $institute_array = $institute_array  . "|" . $institute; 
 }

 $institute_array = "/\b(" . $institute_array . ")\b/i";

// create a multidimensional array of educations  
$educations = unserialize ($row['educations']);
$count_education = count($educations);
$educations= implode (" ; " , $educations);
$education_list = (explode (" ; ", $educations));
$education_array = array();

// check and compare both array

if ($educations == NULL ) 
 $code_institute = 'Not Listed';
else {
for($i=0; $i<$count_education; $i++) {
       list ($org, $degree, $major, $start_date, $end_date) = explode(' ,, ', $education_list[$i]);

       $education_array[$i] = array(
   'org' => trim($org),
       'degree' => trim($degree),
   'location' => trim($location)
   );

   if (preg_match ($institute_array, $education_list[$i], $matched)) {
           $code_institute = 'Matched';
       $match_no_institute = $match_no_institute + 1;
    }

   else 
    $code_institute = 'Not Matched';

 print_r ("<br> Education : (" . ($i+1) . ") Matching Time: " . $match_no_institute . " Code: " . $code_institute . "   " . $matched[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: looks like poor original db design - you should normalise it first

Comment: Shouldn't you be using MySQL to serach for the records instead of PHP?

Comment: I agree with Dragon.  You're defeating the purpose of storing the data in a relational database with that design.  Break apart `Educations` into multiple tables.

Comment: I understand that my solution is not efficient. I am new to mysql and php, would you be able to walk me through how to search using MySQL or any other search functions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but unless you are searching an indexed column you are going to have a bad time. I have never heard of anyone trying to search an "array" that's been serialized or put into some sort of an array fashion in a LONGTEXT or varchar field.

Generally speaking, you should use join tables and associations to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I understand that my solution is not efficient. I am new to mysql and php, would you be able to walk me through how to search using MySQL or any other search functions? thanks